# Convert to shortcode?

Tags: plugins, ajax, buttons

I found a plugin that does mostly what I want. But hoping it could be rewritten as a shortcode to only show where I want it to, not on every post.

this is the js love.js

```
jQuery( document ).on( 'click', '.love-button', function() {
var post_id = jQuery(this).data('id');
jQuery.ajax({
    url : postlove.ajax_url,
    type : 'post',
    data : {
        action : 'post_love_add_love',
        post_id : post_id
    },
    success : function( response ) {
        jQuery('#love-count').html( response );
    }
});

return false;
```

})

And the php ajax-test.php

```
    <?php
/**
 * Plugin Name: Post Love
 * Plugin URI: http://danielpataki.com
 * Description: Allows users to love your posts
 * Version: 1.0.0
 * Author: Daniel Pataki
 * Author URI: http://danielpataki.com
 * License: GPL2
 */

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'ajax_test_enqueue_scripts' );
function ajax_test_enqueue_scripts() {
    if( is_single() ) {
        wp_enqueue_style( 'love', plugins_url( '/love.css', __FILE__ ) );
    }

    wp_enqueue_script( 'love', plugins_url( '/love.js', __FILE__ ), array('jquery'), '1.0', true );

    wp_localize_script( 'love', 'postlove', array(
        'ajax_url' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' )
    ));

}

add_filter( 'the_content', 'post_love_display', 99 );
function post_love_display( $content ) {
    $love_text = '';

    if ( is_single() ) {

        $love = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'post_love', true );
        $love = ( empty( $love ) ) ? 0 : $love;

        $love_text = '<p class="love-received"><a class="love-button" href="' . admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php?action=post_love_add_love&post_id=' . get_the_ID() ) . '" data-id="' . get_the_ID() . '">give love</a><span id="love-count">' . $love . '</span></p>'; 

    }

    return $content . $love_text;

}

add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_post_love_add_love', 'post_love_add_love' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_post_love_add_love', 'post_love_add_love' );

function post_love_add_love() {
    $love = get_post_meta( $_REQUEST['post_id'], 'post_love', true );
    $love++;
    update_post_meta( $_REQUEST['post_id'], 'post_love', $love );
    if ( defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) && DOING_AJAX ) { 
        echo $love;
        die();
    }
    else {
        wp_redirect( get_permalink( $_REQUEST['post_id'] ) );
        exit();
    }
}
```

Finally the css love.css

```
.entry-content .love-button {
    background: #f14864;
    color: #fff;
    padding:11px 22px;
    display:inline-block;
    border:0px;
    text-decoration: none;
    box-shadow: 0px 6px #d2234c;
    position:relative;
}

.entry-content .love-button:hover{
    top:3px;
    box-shadow: 0px 3px #d2234c;
}

.entry-content .love-button:active{
    top:6px;
    box-shadow: none;
}


#love-count {
    background: #eee;
    box-shadow: 0px 6px #ddd;   
    color: #666;
    padding:11px 22px;
    display:inline-block;
}
```

I would really appreciate the help to make this a shortcode, so it deploys the button on by using a shortcode since I only need it showing in 1 page on the whole wordpress site I'm developing.

Answer (score 1):

Look into the add_shortcode function, which can be part of the plugin (although I don't recommend modifying other's plugins, since your changes will be overwritten if they send out an update.

So you would add this function to your 'child theme' function.php

```
function add_my_shortcode() 
{
    add_shortcode('your-shortcode-name', 'the_function_for_your_shortcode');
}
add_action('init', 'add_my_shortcode');
```

..and here is the function that takes the [your-shortcode-name] and outputs some text:

```
function the_function_for_your_shortcode()
{
   return 'here is my shortcode text'; // Shortcode output should be returned
}
```

Now, whenever you put the [your-shortcode-name] in a post/page, it will be replaced with the 'here is my shortcode text'.

A simple (and somewhat useless) example, but it should get you started.